# Take updated field's value from last sibling record

Tags: record-type, field-update, update

I have a custom object `Finance__c` which is a child of Contact with fields:

- Amount__c (Number type),
- Type__c (Picklist),
- Balance__c( Formula),
- and few other formula fields

When I create a new `Finance__c` with some amount in Amount__c, the formula field updates the value in `Balance__c` which actually checks whether `Type__c` is 'Buy' or 'Sell'.

Depending on the picklist value, the formula field  "Balance__c" gets updated.

Now if I create a new `Finance__c` for that same Contact, the new `Finance__c` should take `Balance__c` amount which was in the last `Finance__c` of the Contact.

It's more like our bank transactions where if we withdraw some cash, it always subtracts and displays the amount from the last transaction. How can this be achieved?

Comment: so, have you tried anything?  SFSE respondents appreciate a good faith effort.  Note that formula fields on an object can't reference sibling objects so you may want to reconsider your data model.

Comment: We cannot change the data type of Balance__c field. It has to be formula. I was thinking of writing a before insert trigger on Finance object. Not sure if it'll work.

Comment: You can't programmatically change the value of a formula field so you won't be able to write a trigger that populates it. You can work around this by populating another field and amending the formula to look in that other field OR some other calculation if the other field isn't populated. Not that it's any of my business, but I don't like the business rule here. Balance isn't a property of any particular transaction, it's a property of the body making the transaction.